# End user login on ubuntu server

Tags: android, mysql, authentication

Sorry if this has already been posted or some where else. I have been looking around and trying to find answers to my question and I might just not be understanding the answers that people are giving me.

My question is how to handle end users login in. What is the exact process that happen. Such as, when they put in their email address and password from an android application for example do I search my database where I keep all my users for any data I want to pass to the application using a select statement like

```
SELECT id from user where app.email == user.email && app.password == user.password
```

That would get me the users `id` only if the users email and password match a record we have on file. Is that a successful login?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Your question is probably not going to go over well because it is too vague, and so many things are involved in doing what you're doing that it is simply not solvable as one questions.  A good intro in my opinion is PHP&MySQL for dummies.  You can probably find it at most book stores.

Comment: For starters SQL doesn't use == only =

Comment: Thanks. I will get a book for this. Just wondering what the term "login" entails for a very basic ubuntu server set up.

Comment: The book I recommended involves setting up a database that allows user logins.  Are you asking about logging into the server itself or are you asking about logging into a web application(website) you're building?  Or possibly are you asking how to log in to your mysql database?